# Apps gone missing after rebooting on jailbroken iPad 4

Tags: ios, jailbreak, bug, cydia, ipad

After school, I was doing research on Canadian Blood Service. I went into pages and than it got stuck. I wait for 3 minutes nothing happened so I hold the lock button and try to shut my iPad down but nothing works, I was listening to music at the same time and the music is still playing. I has to do a hard reset by holding home button and lock button. After the reset I found out that every single app has gone missing except for the Stock apps which comes with the phone, and my jailbreaking app suck as Cydia ifile, IAP Free and etc. I reboot many times but nothing happened. The apps are still taking up the storage but I can't see them in usage not search.
Does anyone have any idea? I urgently needs help.

Thanks. and here's my iPad's info: iPad 4 White Wi-Fi 32 GB, jailbroken with Evasion 7 IOS 7.0.4 system.

Answer (score 0):

Your apps haven't been deleted — it's a Springboard glitch where the apps aren't shown. Try…

- Install (or reinstall) a tweak in Cydia, then respring.
- Delete `/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist` then respring.

Comment: Thanks, but i can't found/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist in ifile, and i already reset my iPad so jailbreak is gone. Do u have any other idea or should i rejailbreak?